# Handling command failures when running out of process

Tags: c#, events, brighter

Our use case is pretty simple, we have a rest endpoint that accepts a request for a password change, we are considering using Brighter (or any other kind of message library) to send of the request to the responsible party.

Since the API does not have any responsibilies related to login/identity, it will need to send of the command to the identity provider.

If something goes wrong with the password change we want to notify the user. What is good practice handling errors happening out-of-process?

Do we send the command, and wait for some kind of response event before we return to the client? Do we need to pool api check if the operation is done and if success or error?

Comment: Brighter cannot be used on the server unless the server is localhost.  You need to use Brighter on Client after the server returns a response.  The server can be on a remote machine from client and does not have access back to the user when on a remote machine.

Comment: Sounds like SignalR could help